# Google analytics views based on user id and company id

Tags: google-analytics

We use Google Analytics for analysis of a web application. In our application we have the following:

- User (unique user id), which can be member of multiple companies
- Company (unique company id), which can have multpile users

In Google Analytics we do set user_id for all tracking to the unique user id. We have then created a view in GA to analyze based on the user id.
So far so good.

We do also want a new dimension, the company id. We want to be able to have all reports is GA based on our unique company id. E.g. all page views made by company "123" should be treated as the same user (or if it's some other thing than user I'm not aware of) in Google Analytics. 
This can of course be done by setting the user_id in GA to our company id instead of the user id. But we want to be able to analyze the data based on both user id and company id.

Is it possible to have both possibilities?

A new property may sort of solve the problem, but I don't want to have to track data to two properties.

Comment: Store the company id as a custom dimension. Since the user id is supposed to be passed in by the server to GA it should not be too difficult to add the company id as custom dimension as well.

Comment: I have the company id as custom dimension. But how do I use that like a user id in all reports. E.g. I want to see a cohort for retention based on unique companies instead of users. Same for all other reports.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't possible within the GA interface. Custom dimensions/metrics are not able to be used in certain reports (e.g. Cohort Analysis, Multi-Channel Funnels, etc.)

As you have already outlined, one option is create a new property and set the company ID as the userID. The only other option is to manually create the reports yourself through extracting the data through the Google Analytics API.